# Get data from deployed Web pages(such as html forms) and store it on local machine?

Tags: sql, flask

I am using Flask to deploy a simple HTML form on the web. When a user interacts with the deployed form I want that data to be stored in a local SQL table created on my system. Is this possible through SQL+FLASK? I have also looked at other platforms like XAMPP, but would like to work with FLASK as I am quite used to it.

Comment: Search in google for `flask crud operations` you will get tons of info

Comment: What I am trying to find out is how will the CRUD operations interact with the database once I deploy the page into cloud?

Comment: Did you do any such in your local machine?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600740/unable-to-insert-data-into-mysql-using-flasksqlalchemy?noredirect=1#comment110713553_62600740